# Vim buffers not unloading

Tags: vim, productivity

I can't make vim to delete or unload buffers when there are not active on a vim panel anymore. I tried placing this on my .vimrc

```
set bufhidden=delete
```

and also

```
set bufhidden=unload
```

But none of them work.

This is causing my vim to crash unexpectedly when it gets loaded with a substantial amount of buffers. I do not want to have to close buffers manually, I want them gone as soon as they are not active on my panels anymore.

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To test, try using using `:bwipeout`.

If that works, `set bufhidden=wipe` is what you need. In the vim `:help` file `windows.txt` it describes the differences between delete, unload and wipe values for bufhidden as:

> Like `:bdelete`, but really delete the buffer. Everything related to the buffer is lost. All marks in this buffer become invalid, option settings are lost, etc. Don't use this unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: It is unclear how this answers the question. Could you please [edit] your post to be a little clearer? Thanks!

Comment: Hope this is better. Good question.

Comment: That's a bit better. So are you suggesting he use `set bufhidden=wipe`?